# Help me finding the limit for the quantity $C$ in the problem given here.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, approximation, numerical-calculus

> **Problem 1.** The central difference approximation for $f''(x)$ is given by,
> $$ D_0^2(f,x,h) = \frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2}$$
> where $h \gt 0$. Prove that
> $$ | D_0^2(f,x,h) - f''(x) | = Ch^2$$
> where $C$ depends on $f$, a $\xi \in [x, x+h]$ and a $\zeta \in [x-h,x]$

> (Hint : You can start by writing each of $f(x + h)$ and $f(x - h)$ into a third-order Taylor polynomial of $h$ plus a remainder term.)

> **Problem 2.** The two numbers $\xi$ and $\zeta$ in **Problem 1** are usually unknown. As a result, $C$ is also unknown. Compute the limit of $C$ as h approaches $0$. (This limit provides an estimate for $C$ when $h$ is small.)

**My answer :**

I've done problem 1 with the hint but I'm having trouble with the problem 2 because no information about $f$ is given.

But since in the hint it is said to use Taylor polynomial, I assume $f$ is differentiable upto at least order $4$.

Now, $$ | D_0^2(f,x,h) - f''(x) | = Ch^2$$ where $C = \frac{f^{(4)}(\xi) + f^{(4)}(\zeta)}{4!}$ (I've calculated it).

Since $f^{(4)}$ exists then can I say that $$\lim_{h\to 0} C \\
= \frac{f^{(4)}(x) + f^{(4)}(x)}{4!}\\
= \frac{f^{(4)}(x)}{12} \ \ ?$$

I don't think I can since it's not said that $f^{(4)}$ is continuous.

Then what is the limit for $C$.

Someone please help me, it's urgent and I really need it.

Thanks.

Comment: You're saying continuity of $f$ at x is enough for that? Yes, do give a solution in detail. I'm curious how continuity of $f$ is used to find the limit.

Comment: I guess you are using the Taylor formula of order $4$ for both $f(x+h)$ and $f(x-h)$ and add them up. This solution is fine if  $f^{(4)}$ is continuous at $x.$ I do not think you can relax that assumption.